# Why doesnt this while loop stop after roll1 and roll2?

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I've created a simple dice roll program.  But the while loop will not stop when 
roll1 and roll2 are equal. And the total is not adding up. The programs runs infinite times, I have to stop it.  Please help.

Output:

```
Roll #1: 1
Roll #2: 2
Total is : 3
Roll #1: 4
Roll #2: 1
Total is : 3
Roll #1: 4
Roll #2: 4
Total is : 3
Roll #1: 2
Roll #2: 5
Total is : 3
Roll #1: 4
Roll #2: 4
Total is : 3
Roll #1: 0
Roll #2: 2
Total is : 3
Roll #1: 4
Roll #2: 3
Total is : 3
```

Source Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class App1
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int roll1 = 1+ r.nextInt(6);
        int roll2 = 1+ r.nextInt(6);
        int total = roll1 + roll2;

        System.out.println("Heres comes the dice!");
        System.out.println();


        while ( roll1 != roll2 )
        {
            System.out.println("Roll #1: "  + roll1);
            System.out.println("Roll #2: "  + roll2);
            System.out.println("Total is : " + total );

        }
        System.out.println("Roll #1: "  + roll1);
        System.out.println("Roll #2: "  + roll2);
        System.out.println("Total is : " + total );


    }
 }
```

Comment: Once you start the loop you are not changing the values. thats y it is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Because inside while loop you don't get new values:

```
while ( roll1 != roll2 )
{
    System.out.println("Roll #1: "  + roll1);
    System.out.println("Roll #2: "  + roll2);
    System.out.println("Total is : " + total );

    roll1 = 1+ r.nextInt(6);
    roll2 = 1+ r.nextInt(6);
    total = roll1 + roll2;
}
```

First time you enter in the while loop `roll1` and `roll2` has a random value, but if you don't change this values with the new lines I added, so you will loop always into the same values you had.

About values of roll1 and roll2 changing, that does not have sense for me, in my computer your code result is:

**Launch1**

```
Total is : 7
Roll #1: 1
Roll #2: 6
Total is : 7
Roll #1: 1
Roll #2: 6
Total is : 7
Roll #1: 1
Roll #2: 6
Total is : 7
```

**Launch2**

```
Total is : 8
Roll #1: 5
Roll #2: 3
Total is : 8
Roll #1: 5
Roll #2: 3
Total is : 8
Roll #1: 5
Roll #2: 3
Total is : 8
```

Comment: I'm sorry (I didn't saw your answer before) but I think that you should put your total variable inside the loop (I also had forgotten it xD).

Comment: ok that worked perfectly but can someone explain what just happened thanks

Comment: @JerryWoods check my explanation, also please, share your `SO`, `Java version` and IDE you're using, the numbers changing in your result are weird....

Comment: I understand it now, Java 8, Eclipse, and I don't know what "SO" is.

Comment: Sorry... SO i meant OS (operating system)... But its not much important here, my Spanish mind xD... Let me check later if in java8 `Random.nextInt()` behaviour has changed. Stay tuned! XD

Comment: uhm.... tested in Java8 and output is the same as Java7 in my computer and also here https://ideone.com/cS4pIF in your console numbers are different in each iteration????

Comment: No it worked after I did what you said. And I have X Yosemite for Mac

Answer (score 1):

You want to roll until the dice rolls are the same, which means:

1. Random values need to be created **inside** the loop. Otherwise either the loop doesn't get executed at all or the loop is an infinite loop.
2. Using a *do-while* loop you get nicer code.

```
Random r = new Random();

System.out.println("Heres comes the dice!");
System.out.println();
int roll1, roll2;
do
{
    roll1 = 1+ r.nextInt(6);
    roll2 = 1+ r.nextInt(6);
    int total = roll1 + roll2;
    System.out.println("Roll #1: "  + roll1);
    System.out.println("Roll #2: "  + roll2);
    System.out.println("Total is : " + total );
} while (roll1 != roll2);
```